# How can I set PHP object as an argument of a PHP function?

Tags: php

PHP is an object oriented programming language, and it supports creating object of a class. But is there any way if I can pass a object of a class as the argument of a php function?

Example:

**Note**: This is not real application code, I have used this for an example.

This is my class.

```
class calculator{

    public $c;
    public $d;
    public function add($a, $b) : void {
       $c = $a+$b;
        $this->c = $c;
    }
    public function sub($a, $b) : void { 
        $d = $a-$b;
        $this->d = $d;
     }

  }
```

And here is the function where I want to pass the argument with the object.

```
function calculate_difference(calculator $cl){
            return $c - $d;
         }
```

And this where I am creating object of the class.

```
  $cal = new calculator();
  $cal->add(5,7);
  print $cal->c;  // Output is 12
  $cal->sub(3,2);
  print $cal->d; // Output is 1
  print calculate_difference($cal); //Output should be 11
```

The output of the `calculate_difference` function's result should be 11. But this is not working. It is showing me this Warnings.

```
Warning: Undefined variable $c in C:\xampp\htdocs\stackoverflow\index.php on line 88

Warning: Undefined variable $d in C:\xampp\htdocs\stackoverflow\index.php on line 88
```

So, how can I pass object as an argument of a php function please? Or what's wrong am I doing?

Comment: In short: Yes we can. But such a broad question is most certainly off-topic, which only underlines: Yes we can.

Comment: This of course begs the follow-up question: you must have tried this yourself before asking here. Did you run into some sort of problem?

Comment: In your example `calculate_difference` is not using the passed object e.g. it should do `$cl->c-$cl->d`.

Answer (score 1):

sure, you can pass the object variable as an argument. 
example:

```
$obj= new MyClass();
myFunction($obj);
```

this calls the function my function by passing the object `$obj` to it.

Comment: And we can use typehint as `myFunction(MyClass $obj);`

Answer (score 0):

yes you can :

```
class test
{
   public  $a;
   public  $b;
}


function sums(test $test)
{
   echo $test->a + $test->b;
}

 $test = new test;
 $test->a = 5;
 $test->b = 2;

 sums($test);//output is 7
```